# How to increase root disk space on my AWS EC2 machine

Tags: linux

How to increase root disk space on my AWS EC2 machine. It was 16GB and I increased it to 48GB, but its still problematic, not sure what to do

```
 lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0 33.3M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
loop1     7:1    0   25M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
loop2     7:2    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2074
loop3     7:3    0 55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop4     7:4    0 67.6M  1 loop /snap/lxd/20326
loop5     7:5    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12398
loop6     7:6    0 70.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21029
loop7     7:7    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12704
xvda    202:0    0   48G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   48G  0 part /

 df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       16197480 16177928      3168 100% /
devtmpfs         4068964        0   4068964   0% /dev
tmpfs            4074932        0   4074932   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             814988    80264    734724  10% /run
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            4074932        0   4074932   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         34176    34176         0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
/dev/loop2         56832    56832         0 100% /snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop1         25600    25600         0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
/dev/loop3         56832    56832         0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop4         69248    69248         0 100% /snap/lxd/20326
/dev/loop5         33152    33152         0 100% /snap/snapd/12398
/dev/loop6         72064    72064         0 100% /snap/lxd/21029
/dev/loop7         33152    33152         0 100% /snap/snapd/12704

 df -hT
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root      ext4       16G   16G  3.1M 100% /
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     796M   79M  718M  10% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0     squashfs   34M   34M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
/dev/loop2     squashfs   56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop1     squashfs   25M   25M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
/dev/loop3     squashfs   56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop4     squashfs   68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/20326
/dev/loop5     squashfs   33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12398
/dev/loop6     squashfs   71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21029
/dev/loop7     squashfs   33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12704
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your disk and the partition the root filesystem is on were resized but not the filesystem itself. It's ext4 so use `resize2fs /dev/xvda1` (without size specified `resize2fs` will resize the filesystem to size of the underlying block device). `ext4` supports online grow so you don't even need to unmount it first.

Comment: Thanks for the huge help